# If Goku and Vegeta fused and transformed into super Saiyan god, would you need another Saiyan to be able to get to super Saiyan god?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z, dragonball-super

Watching *Battle of Gods* got me thinking:

If Goku and Vegeta fused, would they need another Saiyan to become a Saiyan god (because one needs five other Saiyans, for a total of six, to become a Saiyan God)?

But since Goku and Vegeta are already fused, I was wondering if they wouldn't.

Who would they use for the 5th person if they needed one? Also, what would happen if you used Broly in the mix?

Comment: Would Broly be considered a 'Pure hearted Saiyan' and hence eligible for the form in the first place?

Comment: @Shisa they never say which type of pure the Saiyan heart needs to be to help form the Super Saiyan God energy.  Since Broly is pure evil, it's probably safe to assume that he is considered a pure hearted Saiyan, just not good.

Comment: Hearing about Resurrection F always sounds like an 8-year old kid making a DBZ fanfic. Where did they even come up with the terminology: "super saiyan god super saiyan"

Answer (score 1):

If Goku and Vegeta were fused, they would need another Saiyan to transform into God Mode.

When they are fused, their souls fused together; I believe when the Grand Kai gives them his earrings to fuse, he says that it's permanent even through death.

While fused they also act as one person; there aren't two minds, it's one mind, they can't argue with each other, or generally influence each other. Even in the temporary fusion that Goten and Trunks use, whoever is the leader has complete control during the fusion.

Comment: Can you use canon quotes etc to add proof to your answer? Does the canon say anything about souls when it comes to this mode, as opposed to just 'power'?

Comment: @shisa i dont have quotes but the grand kai was explaining that the fusion with the earrings was permanent persisting through death, so at least in that form of fusion its pretty safe to say they are literally 1 person. anything else though is speculation.

Comment: @Himarm, your answer is slightly contradictory.  You say that the Potara fusion creates one soul, mind, and body, and you are correct.  Vegito is no longer Goku or Vegeta, it's a completely new person.  However, you mention that Gotenks is controlled by whomever is in the lead, which is not true.  Just like the Potara fusion, the fusion dance creates a completely new person, there is no separate mind, they become one person, just like with the permanent fusion.

Comment: I know this is a little late, but you may want to review the answer now. Dragonball Super has basically retconed the detail about the potara fusion being permanent, claiming it only works that way for Kai. Worth noticing is that the only apparent reason for this cerberus retcon was to justify why Vegito was able to fight only for about 10 minutes after his reappearance during the Zamasu arc.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that since Resurrection F

> both Vegeta and Goku can turn into Super Saiyan Gods.

We can most definitely conclude that their fused version would be able to.

If we go back before this, I'm fairly certain they would be able to in a fused form. As upon turn into a Super Saiyan God Gokus base energy is set to that of the SSJG level which means he's able to attain it again. Once fused the body would be able to recognise this significant power and also replicate it, in the same way that Goku does after Battle of Gods.

I can't find the evidence I'm looking for at the moment, but I'm fairly certain Vegito/Gogeta is able to turn into SSJ3 whereas Vegeta never achieves this level.